# How to find the substitutions that convert the starting sequence into the final sequence? CCC19J5

Tags: algorithms, recursion, divide-and-conquer, context-sensitive, programming-contest

Here is [Canadian Computing Competition 2019 Junior problem 5 on dmoj.ca](https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc19j5). You can also see [the original problem at cemc.uwaterloo.ca](https://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2019/stage%201/juniorEF.pdf) as well.

> A substitution rule describes how to take a sequence of symbols and convert it into a different sequence of symbols. For example, **ABA→BBB**, is a substitution rule which means that **ABA** can be replaced with **BBB**. Using this rule, the sequence **AABAA** would be transformed into the sequence **ABBBA** (the substituted symbols are in bold).
>
> In this task, you will be given three substitution rules, a starting sequence of symbols and a final sequence of symbols. You are to use the substitution rules to convert the starting sequence into the final sequence, using a specified number of substitutions.
>
> For example, if the three substitution rules were:
>
> **AA → AB**
>   **AB → BB**
>   **B → AA**
>
> We could convert the sequence **AB** into **AAAB** in 4 steps, by the following substitutions:
>
> **AB → BB → AAB → AAAA → AAAB**,
>
> where the symbols to be replaced are shown in bold. More specifically, from the initial sequence **AB**, substitute rule 2 starting at position 1, to get the result **BB**. From **BB**, substitute rule 3, starting at position 1, to get the result **AAB**. From **AAB**, substitute rule 3, starting at position 3, to get the result **AAAA**. From **AAAA**, substitute rule 1, starting at position 3, to get the result **AAAB**, which is the final sequence.
>
> **Input Specification**
>
> The first three lines will contain the substitution rules. Each substitution rule will be a sequence of `A`'s and `B`'s, followed by a space following by another sequence of `A`'s and `B`'s. Both sequences will have between one and five symbols.
>
> The next line contains three space separated values, $S$, $I$ and $F$. The value $S(1\le S\le 15)$ is an integer specifying the number of steps that must be used, and the values $I$ (the initial sequence) and $F$ (the final sequence) are sequences of `A`'s and `B`'s, where there are at least one and at most 5 symbols in $I$ and at least one and at most 50 symbols in $F$.
>
> For 7 of the 15 marks available, $S\le 6$.
>
> For an additional 7 of the 15 available marks, $S\le 12$.
>
> ***Output Specification***
>
> The output will be $S$ lines long and describes the substitutions in order.
>
> Line $i$ of the output will contain three space-separated values, $R_i$, $P_i$, and $W_i$:
>
> $R_i$ is the substitution rule number (either 1, 2 or 3) that will be used.
>   $P_i$ is the starting position index of where the substitution rule will be applied in the sequence. Notice that the string is 1-indexed (i.e., the first character of the string is at index 1).
>   $W_i$ is the sequence that results from this substitution. Specifically, $W_i$ is the sequence of symbols that results by applying substitution rule $R_i$ starting at position $P_i$ from the previous sequence of symbols, $W_{i−1}$, where we define $W_0$ to be the initial sequence $I$. Note that $W_S=F$, the final sequence.
>
> There will always be at least one sequence of $S$ substitutions that will convert $I$ into $F$. If there is more than one possible sequence of substitutions, any valid sequence will be accepted.

I tried using recursion but the program isn't fast enough. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please follow our rules for identifying copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  In particular, you should clearly indicate which material was copied from another source.  If your question consists primarily or almost entirely of copied material, it probably isn't suitable here.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving contest-style questions for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lookup “depth first” and “breadth first” search. I’d guess you tried depth first and it fails. Try breadth first, and make sure that when a sequence can be produced in two or more ways, you ignore the second and further ways.